# Maya Python: offsetting a sound file

Tags: python, audio, maya

still pretty new to python.

i am trying to offset a soundfile (.wav format) in maya, so it would start at frame 1001.

i tried using the `sound` command with the `file` and `offset` flags.

```
cmds.sound(file="soundName.wav", offset=1001)
```

Also tried without the ".wav" suffix, as in the audio options tab the filename ist just "soundName", without suffix. Not working tho either.

i just get the error:

```
file is not a sound file
```

Its almost as if the wrong thing gets selected, which may not be a soundfile. 
Because why else would it tell me "soundName" is not a soundfile when it clearly is? Or does maya not interpret WAVs as soundfile? is it just due to the file format?

If i offset the WAV manually, its working fine and maya is playing the file as it should, so maya is clearly working with WAVs, maybe its just the command not working with WAVs?

what am i missing here ?

and why does stackoverflow keeps cutting my first sentence off my posts?
Its always as if i wouldnt say hello, which i usually do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It definitely works. Don't forget to assign a full path.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

cmds.sound(file="/Users/swift/Desktop/soundFile.wav", offset=50)
```

If Maya doesn't wanna play `.wav` file, try to change a codec and other parameters in this file. You need to save your sound file with the following settings: `linear PCM` encoding, `8-bit` unsigned integer, sample rate `22kHz` or `44,1kHz`.

Comment: wow, i imported the soundfile first, then tried to access is via the "sound" command. i didnt unterstand this command to act as an import option for sound. my bad. thanks, adding a path did solve the problem. i was confused by the maya docs, as it reads: File(f)  Name of sound file.